# Windows: How to force Android Emulator to use Intel HAXM

Tags: android, qemu, android-studio, android-x86

Emulator tries to use WHPX instead of HAXM. Both HyperV and Windows Hypervisor Platform feature disabled.

However log shows when running emulator from command line, it still tries to use WHPX via "-enable-whpx" flag thus crashing the emulator. How to force emulator to use HAXM?

```
emulator: Checking whether Windows Hypervisor
Platform (WHPX) is available.
emulator: WinHvPlatform.dll found. Looking for WHvGetCapability...
emulator: WHvGetCapability found. Querying WHPX capabilities...
emulator: WHvGetCapability failed. hr=0x00000000 whpx_cap.HypervisorPresent? 0

emulator: WHPX is either not available or not installed.
emulator: CPU Acceleration: working
emulator: CPU Acceleration status: HAXM version 7.2.0 (4) is installed and usable.
emulator: checking cpu acceleration from main qemu params
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = ".\emulator64-x86.exe"
emulator: argv[01] = "-dns-server"
emulator: argv[02] = "192.168.0.1,fec0:0:0:ffff::1,fec0:0:0:ffff::2,fec0:0:0:ffff::3"
emulator: argv[03] = "-serial"
emulator: argv[04] = "null"
emulator: argv[05] = "-serial"
emulator: argv[06] = "null"
emulator: argv[07] = "-enable-whpx"
emulator: argv[08] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[09] = "<path>\hardware-qemu.ini"
emulator: argv[10] = "-append"
emulator: argv[11] = "qemu=1 no_timer_check androidboot.hardware=goldfish androidboot.serialno=EMULATOR28X0X16X0 clocksource=pit no-kvmclock android.qemud=1 console=0 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=1 qemu.opengles.version=131072 ndns=4 loop.max_part=7 qemu.dalvik.vm.heapsize=256m"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 .\emulator64-x86.exe -dns-server 192.168.0.1,fec0:0:0:ffff::1,fec0:0:0:ffff::2,fec0:0:0:ffff::3 -serial null -serial null -enable-whpx -android-hw <path>/hardware-qemu.ini -append 'qemu=1 no_timer_check androidboot.hardware=goldfish androidboot.serialno=EMULATOR28X0X16X0 clocksource=pit no-kvmclock android.qemud=1 console=0 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=1 qemu.opengles.version=131072 ndns=4 loop.max_part=7 qemu.dalvik.vm.heapsize=256m'
VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:159: Found: 3 adb executables
VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:161: Adb: <SDK path>\platform-tools\adb.exe
VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:161: Adb: <SDK path>\platform-tools\adb.exe
VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:161: Adb: <SDK path>\platform-tools\adb.exe
VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:180: Path:<SDK path>\platform-tools\adb.exe     protocol version: 40 VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:180: Path:<SDK path>\platform-tools\adb.exe protocol version: 40 VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:180: Path:<SDK Path>\platform-tools\adb.exe protocol version: 40 VERBOSE: AdbHostServer.cpp:95: Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037
emulator: Warning: config.ini contains invalid skin.path entry: (null)
emulator: Starting QEMU main loop
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
.\emulator64-x86.exe: invalid option -- '-enable-whpx'emulator: Done with QEMU main loop
emulator: User-config was not changed.
```

Comment: It doesn't look like it is crashing. It is detecting an invalid option (whpx not available but forced on) and is exiting gracefully.

Comment: How are you launching the emulator?

Comment: Do you have virtualisation enabled for your CPU in your BIOS?

Comment: @spikey_richie, CPU and UEFI on Surface Pro4 supports the required virtualization. HyperV ran well with hardware acceleration previously, but is disabled to enable HAXM v7.2(can't coexist with HAXM). Emulator started within Android studio's interface works with HAXM as well. However, starting manually with custom images via commandline does not work as expected.

Comment: @Mokubai
The emulator is launched via the commandline: `.\emulator64-x86.exe -verbose -sysdir <image path> -system <image path>\system.img -ramdisk <image path>\ramdisk.img -data <image path>\userdata.img -kernel <Sdk path>\system-images\android-25\google_apis\x86\kernel-qemu -memory 1024 -partition-size 2047 -gpu host -skindir <Sdk path>\skins -skin pixel_silver`.

The emulator images I am using this [image files](https://github.com/uber/nanoscope-art/releases/download/0.2.2/nanoscope-emulator-0.2.2.zip)